# What is the meaning of the word "crack" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm watching a movie called "The Deer Hunter" There is a wedding scene in which one of the characters is getting married. All the guests are already drunk and the bride and groom are getting ready to leave for the wedding night in their Cadillac. He and a couple of his male friends as well as the bride and a couple of her girlfriends are going outside leaving guests in the club where the party is taking place. It's clear in the movie that this is the time when everyone is trying to find someone with whom they could spend the night and a lot of ladies are being hit on. There is one lady talking to a character played by Robert De Niro and he rests his arm around her while talking to her. The other character played by John Cazale comes up to them and sort of pulls her out of his arm embraces her and tries to kiss her while saying "Come here, give me a **crack**" I think it's a lady that he slapped in the face in a scene before because she was dancing with another guy and he was touching her butt, but it's hard to tell who she really is as she stands with her back turned during this shot.

Does the **crack** mean?

29. a chance; try: I'd like a crack at that job.(source TFD)

He tells her to give him a chance to maybe sleep with him or to forgive him for slapping her in the face.

or

8. A moment; an instant: at the crack of dawn. (source TFD)

He tells her to give him a moment of her time. Although I'm not sure if the word **crack** can be used like this.

or perhaps the word **crack** means something else?

Comment: More like 29 than 8 but it might be intended as a triple pun: the various idiomatic or even crude meanings of the word... for example ["crack a smile"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Crack+a+Smile).

Answer (score -1):

I think it means: Give me a chance. / Give me an opportunity.

There is another similar idiom and it goes like this:

to give somebody a fair crack of the whip = to give someone the opportunity to do something, especially so that they can show that they are able to do it

"Give me a crack" could be a shortened version of the above idiom.